# Generating random data in python fitting given function

Tags: python, numpy, random, statistics, gaussian

I want to generate data in python as if it was some experimental points. I want to get noisy exponential decrease, with noise and it's errors normally distributed. Like this picture, but exponential: [noisy polynomial data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqPA4.png).
Will it be okay if I simply take exponential curve and add some Gaussian noise to it and also generate random errors like this

```
import numpy as np
errors = np.random.normal(0,1,100)
```

Or it can be done in a more intellectual way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution to the problem. I don't know if it is right way to do it, but I still did it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as st
import random 
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

#number of data points
n = 50

#function
def func(data):
    return 10*np.exp(-0.5*data)

def fit(data, a, b):
    return a*np.exp(b*data)

#define interval 
a = 0
b = 4

#generate random data grid
x = []
for i in range(0, n):
    x.append(random.uniform(a, b))
x.sort()

#noise-free data points
yclean = []
for i in range(0, n):
    yclean.append(func(x[i]))

#define mean, standard deviation, sample size for 0 noise and 1 errors
mu0 = 0 
sigma0 = 0.4
mu1 = 0.5 
sigma1 = 0.02

#generate noise 
noise = st.norm.rvs(mu0, sigma0, size = n)
y = yclean + noise
yerr = st.norm.rvs(mu1, sigma1, size = n)

#now x and y is your data 
#define analytic x and y
xan = np.linspace(a, b, n)
yan = []
for i in range(0, n):
    yan.append(func(xan[i]))

#now estimate fit parameters 
#initial guesses
x0 = [1.0, 1.0]
#popt are list of optimal coefficients, pcov is covariation matrix
popt, pcov = curve_fit(fit, x, y, x0, yerr)

fity = []
for i in range(0, n):
    fity.append(fit(xan[i], *popt))

print 'function used to generate is 10 * exp( -0.5 * x )'
print 'fit function is', popt[0], '* exp(', popt[1], '* x )'  

#plotting data and analytical function 
plt.rc("figure", facecolor="w")
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='serif',size = 16)    
plt.title("Data", fontsize=20)
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr, fmt='o')
plt.plot(xan, yan, 'r')
plt.plot(xan, fity, 'g')
plt.show()
```